# JS Click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple onclick not firing.

creating divs in a loop containing the classes:

```
class="person glyphicon glyphicon-user"
```

and i've tried selecting the class the only way i know

```
$('.person')click(function(){
console.log("something";
});
```

it just won't work, i can however print them all with the same selector, and i can fire onclick events on

```
$('body div').click
```

so its a div with class person, which leaves me clueless

thanks in advance.

edit: no browser errors, no action, nothing.
the method copy pasted from my code:

```
$('.person').click(function() {
    console.log("something");
});
```

Comment: did you wrapped your click function from `.ready` ?

Comment: may be due to the missing dot before the click!

Comment: also a syntax error missing `dot` ... `$('.person').click()`. Use browser console to look for errors thrown

Comment: you missed "." $('.person').click

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: yeah the "." is a typo, sadly only in here..

Comment: copy pasted from code: $('.person').click(function() {
 console.log("something");
});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple possible issues ( and *assuming those are only typo's in your question*):

1. Ensure you have jQuery added to your html file and all other jQuery usage comes after that link.
2. Ensure your JS is wrapped by a `$(document).ready(function(){});`
3. "creating divs in a loop containing the classes:" This leads to believe you are creating them via a JS loop? If it is then you need to call your `$('.person').click(function(){});` after the loop. Creating an event on an element type ( *class* in this case ) does not apply to future elements.

Comment: im creating the divs in a loop when Start is pressed. so my click event is added before the divs i suppose. any ideas on how to "add" my click event after start is pressed?

Comment: put the click in a function and called it after start, thanks :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/fs7jpqnc/ haha awe. Just made the jsfiddle as an example. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

try to use [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click

```
$( ".person" ).on( "click", function() {
console.log("something");
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to figure out your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the element with class "person" is dynamically created. Either way, try:

```
$("body").on("click", ".person", function() {
    console.log("something");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If its not solved yet, Try this way too

```
$(document).on('click','.person',function(){
   console.log("something");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a dot after the jquery selector :

```
$('.person')click(function(){
   // something
});
```

should be

```
$('.person').click(function(){
   // something
});
```

Also, ensure your click handler is declared after the `div` with class `person`

Edit, as it seems it is a typo only in your question and not in your code.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).off('click','.person').on('click','.person',function(){
console.log('hello world');

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.person').click(function(){
alert('helloooo...')
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="person">click me</button>
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you have done as below. But try this trouble shooting:

First of all, check if you imported `jquery.min.js`correctly, which includes correct path to jquery.

Then, check if your script loads only after `jquery.min.js` is loaded.

Once, again please make sure your code (or script) is fired or called only after jquery.min.js is loaded.

If this is ok, then, check if, in between any script fails to execute, as if any script fails to run in between, the code following it will be skipped. I mean to say like:

```
line in which your `jquery.min.js`
.
.
.
.
.
Some code that is error prone
.
.
.
.
.
And at last your script lies (which wont fire)
```