# Handling .click() in the Safari browser

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, browser, safari

Faced with a problem, element.click() event doesn't work in Safari browser.

I need after clicking on the button, to click on the element in the layout.
This works on all platforms and browsers except Safari\IOS.

Here is all the code:

```
const whatDevice2 = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
let whatEventUse2 = whatDevice2 ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

let play = document.querySelector('#app-2 .cp-play-icon.cp-play-icon-paused');
let originalId = audioPlay2[index].dataset.originalId;
let elementToClick = document.querySelector(#${originalId});
let audioButton = popupElement2.querySelector('a.popup__description_audio');
        
audioButton.addEventListener(whatEventUse2, () => {
  if (elementToClick.classList.contains('cp-playlist-link_current')) {
    play.click();
    setTimeout(addIdLi2, 0);
  } else {
    elementToClick.click();
    { setTimeout(addIdLi2, 0);
   }
 });
```

Apparently there is some subtlety that I don't see, and the ways I found on the internet didn't help.
If anyone has any knowledge in this matter, please give me advice on what to do or point me in the right direction).
I would be glad to have any information, thank you!

Tried various tricks like emulating touch event through a function:

```
let clickEvent = new Event('click', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  view: window
});
```

Replace play.click(); with play.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

Added a style to all clickable elements:

`cursor: pointer;`

I put a check to add the event depending on the platform:

```
const whatDevice2 = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
let whatEventUse2 = whatDevice2 ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794467/js-click-not-working